# Tomcat - java classes not being included in my jsp pages

Tags: java, class, jsp, tomcat

I added a new Context in server.xml to move ROOT dir for my webapps, like so:

```
<Context path="" docBase="../sites" debug="0" reloadable="true" >
    <Resource name="jdbc/myphoto" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"
    url="jdbc:derby:C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.12\sites\webtech\WEB-INF\lib\photo"
    maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" /> 
</Context>
```

Now for some reason, tomcat cannot find my custom java classes. My jsp page looks like so:

```
... some xhtml ...
<%@ page import="com.domain.webtech.Hello" %>
<%
    Hello h = new Hello();
    out.print(h.hello());
%>
```

And I can a Hello.java file in **sites/webtech/WEB-INF/classes/com/domain/webtech/** which is very simple:

```
package com.somename.webtech;
public class Hello {
public Hello() {
}
public String hello() {
    return "hello, world!";
}
}
```

I compiled it and even packaged it into a webtech.jar file and placed it in **sites/webtech/WEB-INF/lib/**

Does anyone have any idea as to why Tomcat is not finding my classes?

Thanks for your time,

G.

Comment: When you packaged it into a jar, did you maintain the directory structure (i.e. the class file should have path com/bravotic/webtech/Hello.class inside the .jar file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docBase` has to point to the web root.

Change

```
<Context docBase="../sites" ...>
```

to

```
<Context docBase="../sites/webtech" ...>
```

And open your JSP by http://localhost:8080/page.jsp instead of http://localhost:8080/webtech/page.jsp.